# Converting a subdirectory in a git repo into an independent git repo

Tags: git, version-control, unfuddle

I have a git repository on Unfuddle. This repo contains multiple projects none of which are individually tracked by git. I happen to work on one of these projects but i have to pull the complete repo everytime before i push the committed changes to my project,because its the entire set of projects that under version control. 
So the repo structure is like this

```
MainRepo
  Project A
  Project B
  Project C
  .git
```

There is no .git in either Project A,B or C.Suppose i work on Project C, can i just work with it individually ?. What would be the steps to do that ?

Thank You

Comment: probably duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository

Comment: Answer would depend on if you want to submit changes back to big repository, or just want to clone small part of original project and never look back to it

Answer (score 0):

use filter branch on a new branch you spawn for each project. Fetch those into individual repos.